# How can I add and remove records from a collection with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the following class called City that contains another class called Detail.

```
 public class City
    {
        public override string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public override string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public class Detail {
            public Detail() {
                Text = new HtmlText();
            }
            public HtmlText Text { get; set; }
        }

}
```

public class HtmlText {

```
public HtmlText()
{
    TextWithHtml = String.Empty;
}
[AllowHtml]
public string TextWithHtml { get; set; }
```

}

In my code I use the following to create a list of details. Later on I populate some of 
the details but not all.

```
IList<City.Detail> Details = Enumerable.Range(1,6).Select(x => new City.Detail()).ToList();
```

I need to be able to do two things. Can someone tell me the best way to do this. Hopefully using LINQ.

- a) Remove any CityDetails from Details that have an empty Text field?
- b) Add to the Details to make it have six City.Detail records if it has less than six?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question can be solved by using this "query":

```
Details = Details.Where(cityDetail=>cityDetail.Text != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityDetail.Text.TextWithHtml)).ToList();
```

This will override ur details var and with the new list, including only the non empty items.

As of ur second question - its not really clear what u want to do, and you need to provide us with some more details/ explanations

**Edit:**

IEnumerable(T) represents a read only collection, which means it doesnt support removing items by definition. Of course you can add ur own RemoveWhere extension method, but it will essentially be doing the same thing ive done here

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is read only, but not `IList<T>`, which is what he's using.  This might not matter, depending on if a reference to the list has already been stored elsewhere.

Comment: You are correct. I mentioned the IEnumerable because he/she asked about a linq query, and I think it generally should be accented that linq is a QUERY language, and as such is mostly inteneded to be used in read-only scenarios

Comment: I am getting an error saying Invalid expression term '=>'. Note that Detail is a class within the City class. When I enter it in I notice that City.Detail are in blue but intellisense doesn't suggest anything after Detail other than equals and reference equals. Can you tell me if there's a problem with the LINQ.

Comment: the Details ive mentioned is the collection u pasted in ur sample (IList<City.Detail> Details). can u paste ur exact code? it seems to work for me here with no issues

Comment: Hello. It works now. Sorry I had changed your code to City.Detail inside the LINQ. Now I realize you were right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@YavgenyP answered your first question well. For the second question, here's what I'd recommend:

```
while (Details.Count < 6)
    Details.Add(new City.Detail());
```

Trying to do this with LINQ is just all-around worse (length, readability, speed):

```
if (Details.Count < 6)
    Enumerable.Range(1, 6 - Details.Count).Select(x =>
    {
        var d = new City.Detail();
        Details.Add(d);
        return d;
    }).ToArray();
```

While I like his solution the best, here are some alternate ways to answer the first question:

```
foreach (var toRemove in Details.Where(cityDetail => cityDetail.Text == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityDetail.Text.TextWithHtml)))
    Details.Remove(toRemove);

foreach (var toRemove in (from cityDetail in Details
                              where cityDetail.Text == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityDetail.Text.TextWithHtml)
                              select cityDetail))
    Details.Remove(toRemove);

(from cityDetail in Details
where cityDetail.Text == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityDetail.Text.TextWithHtml)
select Details.Remove(cityDetail)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the LINQ. Note that Detail is a class within the class City so it should read "City.Detail".

Answer (score 0):

a)

```
Details = 
   Details
   .Except(Details
       .Where(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Text.TextWithHtml)))
   .ToList();
```

b)

```
 Details = 
    Details
      .Concat(
        Enumerable
        .Range(1, 6 - Details.Count())
        .Select(x => new City.Detail()))
      .ToList();
```